# How to create a Button with two separated Texts and background colors in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to recreate this button:
[image]

The button has two different background colors and a Text in each section. The "click" is unique, so it doesn't matter which side the user will click.

I tried this code, but the containers aren't covering the entire area of the button.

EDIT: complete widget tree below

```dart
Card(
                elevation: 3.0,
                shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Container(
                 
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("${data["teams"]}"),
                      Row(

                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {  },
                              child: Row(

                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                                    child: Text("1"),
                                  ),
                                  Container(color: Colors.white,)
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {  },
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                                        child: Text("X"),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(color: Colors.white,),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {  },
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                                        child: Text("2"),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(color: Colors.white,),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                        ],
                      )

                    ],
                  )
                )

            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap row with clickable widget like InkWell, or `GestureDetector` to get tap event

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: kToolbarHeight,
  width: 200,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 4,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
              child: Text("1"),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text("1.24"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Card(
                elevation: 3.0,
                shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("{data[]}"),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                child: Text("1"),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                        Expanded(
                            child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                  child: Text("X"),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                        Expanded(child: myButton()),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ClipRRect myButton() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 4,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                child: Text("1"),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 6,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text("1.24"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: My button has no fixed size but it is wrapped in `Expanded`. Will this work anyways?

Comment: Hope it would, but if you could provide more about parent widget, It would be easy to test it out.

Comment: I've just added the entire widget tree

Comment: Does this produce error on your test case.

Comment: I need to use `Expanded` because I have 3 button in a row, so I have to remove SizedBox. And if I remove it, it produce `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#815a6 relayoutBoundary=up16
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Comment: It is working in my case with top level `Column` widget, What is the parent of this `Card` widget

Comment: The Card is inside a `FutureBuilder`, that is inside a Column

Comment: BTW I've wrapped it with `Expanded`

Comment: Ok thank you, now it's working for me. Even if it is not a proper button I think it could work

Comment: A better way of doing this will be using `LayoutBuilder` on body and using its constrains . Also providing flex will do some changes on UI look

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding the property `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in your row:

```
Row(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
         children: [
              Expanded(
                   child: Container(
                         color: Colors.redAccent,
                         child: Text("1"),
                         ),
                        ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(color: Colors.white,),
                      )
                   ]
                ),
```

Comment: The following error is shown : `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#a8e29 relayoutBoundary=up16
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Comment: hum I see, your Button should have an infinite height, so setting `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` throws this. Try to wrap your Button in a SizedBox with a static  width and height. If you can't do that my solution isn't going to be perfect

Comment: I have 3 button in a row that are wrapped with `Expanded` so it can't be static in my usecase. Thank you anyway!